# Erro de: Unauthorized

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin-forms

Baixei um projeto para testar o envio de push notification. Estou tentando de várias formas e sem sucesso. Esse projet é de um cara chamado **HabibAli**. Quando rodo dá o erro de

> Unauthorized

Esse é o código do programa para envio de notificações

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using FirebaseNet.Messaging;
using System;

namespace MessageSender
{
    class MessageSender
    {



        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task t = new Task(async () =>
            {
                await foo();
            });
            t.Start();


            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static async Task<IFCMResponse> foo()
        {
            FCMClient client = new FCMClient("AIzaSyAmf6JBNd2f0n4De-1DdPJdJiWfDbGhDVI"); //as derived from https://console.firebase.google.com/project/
            var message = new Message()
            {
                To = "778532852741", //topic example /topics/all
                Notification = new AndroidNotification()
                {
                    Body = "great match!",
                    Title = "Portugal vs. Denmark",
                }
            };
            var result = await client.SendMessageAsync(message);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

O programa FCM está rodando no meu Cel(Rodei hoje pela manhã) e também já não consigo mais. Como ele foi implantado a primeira vez, está funcionando, mas não consigo mais rodá-lo, inclusive abri um post pra isso.

Comment: Isso ai talvez seja problema com a serverKey gerada no Firebase. Eu nunca usei Xamarin, por isso não estou conseguindo te ajudar tanto. =/

Comment: 100% de chance que é a server key. Você tem que criar um projeto para seu app no firebase, pegar o arquivo json que ele gera e colocar no root do projeto. Depois pegar a server key que foi gerada pra você e trocar no construtor do FCMClient. Segue o tutorial que tem para java que no Xamarin é a mesma coisa. Ou muda pro OneSignal que faz a mesma coisa.

Comment: Dê uma olhada nessa issue: https://github.com/rlamasb/Firebase.Xamarin/issues/25

Comment: @GrupoCDSInformática, esse OneSignal é o que. Um ambiente de desenv ou servidor de mensagens? Você disse para pegar o json gerado. E onde eu pego esse arquivo? Onde ele fica? Não é o **google-service.jason** é?

Comment: No Github do próprio autor ele ensina a configurar todo o processo do push notification: https://github.com/HabibAli/FCM-Xamarin-Forms

Comment: Fui montando o passo a passo, removendo os erros e quando não deu mais erro, dá o erro de: **An unhandled exception ocurred**. Minha aplicação consome um serviço.

Comment: @GrupoCDSInformática, eu coloco o que? O SENDER_ID ou PROJECT_ID? e a API KEY é essa(Chave de API da Web)? Quando eu criei o projeto apareceu uma chave grande chamada Server Key, mas não consigo mais encontrá-la no firebase, acho que é essa, certo?

Comment: Se não me engano eh a server Key mesmo, mas se entrar nas configurações do projeto (acho que eh a engrenagem) lá tem, em cloud messaging.

Comment: @GrupoCDSInformática, é a server key mesmo. Já confirmei, qualquer valor diferente dela dá esse erro. Só que até abri outro post, pois agora tá dando erro de registro inválido.